# Trivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$

Tags: probability

Consider a trivariate normal vector (X, Y, Z) with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. How to construct a covariance matrix that X, Y  are conditionally independent given Z but X, Y are not marginally independent.

I think  $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 1 & 0 \\
    1  & 1 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ can fulfill the requirement but I don't know how to show it conditionally independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any example where $cov(X,Y) \neq 0$ and take $Z=X$.

Comment: Why need to take Z = X? Do you mean Var(X) = Var(Z)?

Comment: Given $X$, $X$ is independent of any random variable since it acts like a constant. So the idea of taking $Z=X$ is to make $X$ and $Y$ independent given $Z$.  In particular you can take $X=Y=Z$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$. @scottjw

Comment: But how to show X = Z in the covariance matrix?

Comment: @scottjw $cov(X,X)=var(X)=1$ so all the elements of the matrix are equal to $1$. (I am taking $X=Y=Z$).

Comment: Thank you. From my understanding, if X, Y are conditionally independent given Z, then it means f(X, Y|Z) = f(X|Z) * f(Y|Z). How can we connect this formula to these covariance matrices?

Comment: In this example densities do not exist, so you cannot use that criterion . But, as I said,  $X$ is constant  when $X$ is given so conditional independence follows immediately.  @scottjw